# Using a try-catch exception, within the catch brackets how do I restart the program if an exception occurs?

Tags: c#, try-catch, repeat

what I am trying to do is use a try-catch exception to restart the program and get the user to reeter the data values again. How would I do this? I tried using a goto to bring it back to the first line but this didn't seem to work. (and the general consensus is that goto's are evil). Any help that could be given greatly appreciated.

```
Console.WriteLine("Please enter the two points that you wish to know the distance between:");
string point = Console.ReadLine();
string[] pointInput = point.Split(' ');


int pointNumber = Convert.ToInt16(pointInput[0]);                        //Stores the actual input number's into two integers
int pointNumber2 = Convert.ToInt16(pointInput[1]);

try                                                                      //Try-Catch statement to make sure that the User enters relevant PointNumbers
{
    double latitude = (Convert.ToDouble(items[pointNumber * 3]));            //
    double longtitude = (Convert.ToDouble(items[(pointNumber * 3) + 1]));    //
    double elevation = (Convert.ToDouble(items[(pointNumber * 3) + 2]));     //

    double latitude2 = (Convert.ToDouble(items[pointNumber2 * 3]));          //
    double longtitude2 = (Convert.ToDouble(items[(pointNumber2 * 3) + 1]));  //
    double elevation2 = (Convert.ToDouble(items[(pointNumber2 * 3) + 2]));   // Uses the relationship between the pointnumber and the array to select the required items from the array.


    //Calculate the distance between two point using the Distance class
    Console.WriteLine("The distance in km's to two decimal places is:");
    Distance curDistance = new Distance(latitude, longtitude, elevation, latitude2, longtitude2, elevation2);
    Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0:0.00}", curDistance.toDistance()) + "km");
}
catch(IndexOutOfRangeException)
{

    Console.WriteLine("You have selected a point number outside the range of the data entered, please select two new pointnumbers");

  // here is where I would have the program restart  

}
```

Comment: What do you mean by restart? If you handled the exception, the program will not terminate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you start learning to program you learn that these situations can be solved using while or do-while loops. Therefore I will give you such answer:

```
            bool restart = false;
            do
            {
                restart = false;
                Console.WriteLine("Please enter the two points that you wish to know the distance between:");
                string point = Console.ReadLine();
                string[] pointInput = point.Split(' ');


                int pointNumber = Convert.ToInt16(pointInput[0]);                        //Stores the actual input number's into two integers
                int pointNumber2 = Convert.ToInt16(pointInput[1]);

                try                                                                      //Try-Catch statement to make sure that the User enters relevant PointNumbers
                {
                    double latitude = (Convert.ToDouble(items[pointNumber * 3]));            //
                    double longtitude = (Convert.ToDouble(items[(pointNumber * 3) + 1]));    //
                    double elevation = (Convert.ToDouble(items[(pointNumber * 3) + 2]));     //

                    double latitude2 = (Convert.ToDouble(items[pointNumber2 * 3]));          //
                    double longtitude2 = (Convert.ToDouble(items[(pointNumber2 * 3) + 1]));  //
                    double elevation2 = (Convert.ToDouble(items[(pointNumber2 * 3) + 2]));   // Uses the relationship between the pointnumber and the array to select the required items from the array.


                    //Calculate the distance between two point using the Distance class
                    Console.WriteLine("The distance in km's to two decimal places is:");
                    Distance curDistance = new Distance(latitude, longtitude, elevation, latitude2, longtitude2, elevation2);
                    Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0:0.00}", curDistance.toDistance()) + "km");
                }
                catch (IndexOutOfRangeException)
                {

                    Console.WriteLine("You have selected a point number outside the range of the data entered, please select two new pointnumbers");
                    restart = true;
                }
            } while (restart);
```

Watch out that if you call Main within Main you can end up making StackOverflowException :-D

Answer (score 1):

As long as it's a console application you can call `Main` method in `catch` block.

```
private static int m_NumberOfRetries = 5; //Define how many times application can "restart" itself to avoid stackoverflow. 

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    try
    {
        //Do something useful
    }
    catch
    {
        m_NumberOfRetries--;
        if (m_NumberOfRetries != 0)
        {
            Main(args);
        }
    }
 }
```

But it's not a good practice to do so. You can avoid this by checking user input in your application.

Comment: This can also lead to an overflow/memory error if he is really unlucky.

Comment: @agarhy Yes, you're right, it's awful way to do it. Actually it's possible to avoid stack overflow by defining how many times `catch` block can call `Main`. I'll edit answer.

Comment: Should you not decrement m_NumberOfRetries before the recursive call, I don't think it will get executed the way you have it now

Answer (score 1):

You should consider validating your input before you operate on it always. Consider creating a specialized method to accept user input and validate it. The method can internally continue to ask for user input until the validation succeeds.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Starts a new instance of the program itself
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(Application.ExecutablePath);

// Closes the current process
Environment.Exit(0);
```

Comment: I would be very surprised if people actually do this for incorrect user input. And if they do, I would love to ask them why :)

Comment: @agarhy I too do not understand the reason to restart the app just because the user is not validated...But,as you have written the suggestion,I thought to write down the code to restart application:=)

Answer (score 0):

Consider only starting to read the input again.
If it is what you need, the following would be suitable:

Put the method getData() in the Distance class. The class Distance must have a nonparametric constructor.

Distance.java

```
private double latitude;
private double longitude;
private double elevation;
private double latitude2;
private double longitude2;
private double elevation2;

public Distance() {}

public boolean getData(){
    Console.WriteLine("Please enter the two points that you wish to know the distance between:");
    string point = Console.ReadLine();
    string[] pointInput = point.Split(' ');
    int pointNumber = Convert.ToInt16(pointInput[0]);
    int pointNumber2 = Convert.ToInt16(pointInput[1]);
    try{
        latitude = (Convert.ToDouble(items[pointNumber * 3]));            //
        longtitude = (Convert.ToDouble(items[(pointNumber * 3) + 1]));    //
        elevation = (Convert.ToDouble(items[(pointNumber * 3) + 2]));     //

        latitude2 = (Convert.ToDouble(items[pointNumber2 * 3]));          //
        longtitude2 = (Convert.ToDouble(items[(pointNumber2 * 3) + 1]));  //
        elevation2 = (Convert.ToDouble(items[(pointNumber2 * 3) + 2]));   // I assume the exception goes from these 6 lines               

        return true;
    } catch (IndexOutOfRangeException) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Main.java:

```
Distance curDistance = new Distance();
while(!curDistance.getData()) 
    Console.WriteLine("You have selected a point number outside the range of the data entered, please select two new pointnumbers"); 
Console.WriteLine("The distance in km's to two decimal places is:");   
Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0:0.00}", curDistance.toDistance()) + "km");
```

The while loop makes the program ask for the input as long as it's incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

```
catch()
{
  console.writeline("Some error");
  private void restart()
   {
    //write Press any key to restart the program 

   //clear the screen;

  //call the main method; 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a big difference in user data entry problems and program execution exceptions and you should have two independant mechanisms to handle each.

User data entry problems (e.g. a user entering "abc" where a number is required) should be handled by an input validation mechanism (written by you). This type of problem is correctable by the user, normally the reason for the validation failure is displayed to the user and the opportunity is given for reentry of the data.

Program execution exceptions are not correctable by the user (e.g. a timeout has occurred attempting to connect to a database) and should be handled using the try/catch mechanism built into the language.

For a number of reasons it is considered poor programming practice to use the try/catch mechanism to provide program flow control (which is what you are attemptring to do).

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who is looking for a generic approach, by merging the answers of **Leri** and **Nikola Davidovic** I've come up with a template that does not use recurrence and is cleaner imho.

```
int numberOfRetriesLeft = 5;
bool shouldRetry = false;

do
{
    shouldRetry = false;
    
    try
    {
        // call the method that needs to support retrying
    }
    catch
    {
        shouldRetry = true;
        numberOfRetriesLeft--;
        // log error
    }
}
while (shouldRetry && numberOfRetriesLeft > 0);
```

It could be further refactored as a wrapper method that accepts `Func` as a parameter, but this is cleaner for an example.